# Join tables via graphql

Tags: java, graphql

I am new to graphql and cannot find a solution for a simple problem.
Assuming there are POJOs:

```
class Book {
  String title;
  String authourName;
}

class Author {
  String name;
  Integer yearOfBirth;
}
```

```
type Book {
    title: String
    authourName: String
}

type Author {
    name: String
    yearOfBirth: String
}
```

How can I specify a query where I can get joined Book with Author on book.authorName = book.name:

```
BookWithAuthor(authorName: "xxx") {
  title
  authourName
  yearOfBirth
}
```

?

Comment: Can't you have `author: Author` in `Book` instead of `authorName: String`? Query would then be `{ title { author { name, yearOfBirth } } }`.

Comment: But how to specify then the relation `book.authorName = author.name` without saving new data to db? It's just a simple example on my real problem: I have many tables and want to join them in one graphql query

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/execution/

Answer (score 0):

You can include Author inside your Book type as :

```
type Author {
    name: String
    yearOfBirth: String
}

type Book {
    title: String
    author: Author
}
```

Then query Book as :

```
Book(authorName: "xxx") {
  title
  Author{
     name
     yearOfBirth
  }
}
```